# I'm trying to connect to the database, seems like the set-up is correct, but for some reason, it says that it is not available

Tags: node.js, mongoose, next.js

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        uri: configService.get<string>(`MONGODB_URI`),
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

I got this error:

> ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (4)...